# Uninstalling Apps from the Dash

Tags: uninstall, unity-dash

Is it possible to uninstall an application (with it relative packages) from the Dashboard without opening the Software Center, searching for it and hitting "Remove"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled the Amazon app by:

1. right-click on the app (on the Dashboard)
2. click unistall